# MySQL query with subquery to slow

Tags: mysql

I have two tables on same database, `Device` and `EventData`; both tables have the columns `accountID` and `deviceID`, which also are primary keys.

In the `Device` table there's a column named `linkDescription`.

I need to duplicate some rows, in the table `EventData`, whose `accountID` and `deviceID`, in the `Device` table, having some text in column `linkDescription`.

Example:

**Device table**

```
accountID  DeviceID linkDescription
12345       5800      444
12345       5700      445
12345       5500      null <--literally null
12388       4400      555
12388       4450      555
```

**EventData table**

```
accountID  DeviceID timestamp
12345       5800      123335544
12345       5700      123335544
12345       5500      123335544
12388       4400      123335544
12388       4450      123335544
12345       5800      123335548
12345       5700      123335549
12345       5500      123335549
12388       4400      123335545
12388       4450      123335546
```

Now I need to duplicate some rows on `EventData` and change the `accountID` using the `linkDescription` from `Device` table; so `EventData` now has the following data:

```
accountID  DeviceID timestamp
12345       5800      123335544
12345       5700      123335544
12345       5500      123335544
12388       4400      123335544
12388       4450      123335544
12345       5800      123335548
12345       5700      123335549
12345       5500      123335549
12388       4400      123335545
12388       4450      123335546
444         5800      123335544 <-duplicated data with new accountID from here
445         5700      123335544
555         4400      123335544
555         4450      123335544
444         5800      123335548
445         5700      123335549
555         4400      123335545
555         4450      123335546
```

So now I'm testing the following query which going to be part of a bigger `INSERT INTO`:

```
explain 
select * 
from EventData
where 
    EventData.accountID in (
        select accountID 
        from Device 
        where Device.linkDescription > '0')
    and EventData.deviceID in (
        select deviceID 
        from Device 
        where Device.linkDescription> '0')
    and timestamp > (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 20 minute));
```

But is two slow, and the `EXPLAIN` command show this:

```
ID   select_type           table      type            posible_keys    key   key_len  ref     rows     Extra
1    PRIMARY              EventData   ALL             null            null   null    null  47555718   Using where
3    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY    Device     ALL             null            null   null    null    8043     Using where
2    DEPENDENT SUBQUERY    Device     index_subquery    PRIMARY     PRIMARY    34    func     3       Using where
```

So, as I understand at least, is checking the whole table and that's why is so slow.

How can I do what I want faster?

Comment: `in` conditions work well with deterministic sets (example: `in (1, 2, 3, 5)` but for subqueries they can be catastrophic, because the subqueries need to be evaluated once for each row. Joins are a faster way to do it

Comment: I have a JAVA module which write on EventData table, so I think I'm going to re write the code to do what I want. I have a VB.NET programs and works doing similar things as you say, making querys separately and creating a new query with all inside of an IN; so no subquery is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from your question what you are trying to do, but you should use `JOIN` to speed things up. Your `SELECT` could be written more like this:

```
SELECT EventData.accountID from
EventData
RIGHT JOIN Device
ON
(
    (
        Device.accountID = EventData.accountID
        OR Device.deviceID = Event.deviceID
    )
    AND Device.linkDescription> '0'
    AND timestamp > (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 20 minute))
);
```

You can probably work out how the `INSERT` would work from there.

Comment: I change the OR by an AND and returns a lot o nulls in one column

Comment: Hmm, can you simplify it to see what's wrong? Maybe take out the last two `AND`s and see if you get something.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using JOINs instead of `where` conditions:

```
select ed.*
from
    EventData as ed
    inner join Device as d1 on ed.accountId = d1.accountId
    inner join Device as d2 on ed.deviceId = d2.deviceId
where
    d1.linkDescription > '0'
    and d2.linkDescription > '0'
    and  ed.timestamp > (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 20 minute));
```

I'm duplicating the `Device` table just to correct your query. If both conditions must be satisfied simultaneously, then just use the `Device` table once:

```
select ed.*
from
    EventData as ed
    inner join Device as d on ed.accountId = d.accountId and ed.deviceId = d.deviceId
where
    d.linkDescription > '0'
    and d.linkDescription > '0'
    and  ed.timestamp > (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 20 minute));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: How many time usually takes querys like those ones on MySQL table with 47 million rows? Cause most querys that I use in my programs takes not longer than a couple of seconds. Maybe I'm expecting too much from the database engine.

Comment: @E_Blue Indeed your table is big, but you need to consider that the `in (select ...)` condition is evaluated once **for every row** in your table, so it's quite a penalty on performance. That's why I recommend using joins. If your tables have the appropriate indexes, that should speed the things up

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessarily your subquery that is slow, its the main table that is 47 million rows:

and timestamp > (unix_timestamp(now()-interval 20 minute));

Add an index on timestamp. That should solve it. I will point out that subqueries and joins have no real difference in performance in modern versions of mysql. joins are cleaner and more easily understood however.

Comment: I already tried with and without timestamp and the EXPLAIN command return the same.